# phpMyAdmin Front Page - Change "Server Charset" to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding, mariadb

I'm trying to get the phpMyAdmin front page to show the "Server Charset" as "UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)". Currently, it is displaying as "cp1252 West European (latin1)".

Is there a config.inc.php setting that I need to change to do this? I initially assumed that it was a setting that needed to be changed on the MySQL database itself...but if you look at the screenshot I provided, you'll see that on my hosting provider's phpMyAdmin instance that connects to the *exact same database*, the Server charset is UTF-8. So this tells me that the Server charset value is somehow controlled by phpMyAdmin. It kind of makes sense too, because you can actually specify a charset when connecting to MySQL via a connection string with the "charset=utf8" option. I just don't know where to specify that in phpMyAdmin.

[image]

Comment: Server means the MySQL server to which you are connecting. So I think you must look in to mysql documentations to find out how to set default collation for your server. For example here is a documentation page  that may give you the answer(remember to check you are reading documentation for the exact version of mysql that you have installed). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html

Comment: By the way, You already have 884 reputation in SO, which is not bad. I'm wondering why you don't go ahead and setup your SO profile yet.

Comment: @rineez I also initially assumed that it was a setting that needed to be changed on the MySQL database itself...but if you look at the second screenshot I provided, you'll see that on another phpMyAdmin instance that connects to the *exact same database*, the Server charset is UTF-8. So this tells me that the Server charset value is somehow controlled by phpMyAdmin. It kind of makes sense too, because you can actually specify a charset when connecting to MySQL via a connection string with the "charset=utf8" option. I just don't know where to specify that in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Hmm interesting.

Comment: See if any of the tips here help: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, for some reason in my case I had to change it manually when working locally on my computer(I use xampp)I don't know if it would work for you as I tried just a lot of different options when working locally but when I uploaded everything to a shared hosting, server charset was  automatically set up to  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)and no set up was required, as well as you I had two instances of the same database but with a different server charset setting. Anyway here's what I did.

1 open file my.ini (xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini)
2 add this before [client]

```
[mysqld]
```

character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci

save

3 stop mysql and apache once, start them again.

4 check if it worked.

I know this question was asked 6 months ago but I didn't find the answer that worked for me in here so I decided to share in the hope of helping anybody with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf8';
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

To your config.inc.php, just look for the name of this file in your server directories. Then restart MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Undry is correct (phpMyAdmin v5.2.0)
It's a phpMyAdmin setting if you want the default for creating new databases to show utf8_general_ci.
See phpMyAdmin docs https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html and
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_DefaultConnectionCollation